# Difficult T-SQL Join/Pivot

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, join

The original way I worded this question would be unhelpful to most, so I've reworked it significantly.

I have a legacy database, whose schema **I have no control over** (nor ever have). The db schema was designed agnostic of the provider for consumption by unmanaged C++, so there are no FK constraints, etc. I come along and need to consume this from .NET, and also need to present the data much differently than it was originally intended.

Here is the schema of the relevant tables (I've bolded/asteriskifed what amount to the keys for this question):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Formats](
[GroupName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
**[BatchID] [bigint] NOT NULL,**
[SeriesNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
**[SequenceID] [bigint] NOT NULL,**
[SeqNum] [int] NOT NULL,
[FormatName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields](
[GroupName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
**[BatchID] [bigint] NOT NULL,**
**[SequenceID] [bigint] NOT NULL,**
[SeqNum] [int] NOT NULL,
**[FieldName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,**
[FieldDisplayName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FieldValue] [ntext] NULL
```

There is a 1:Many relationship between Formats:Fields.

I need to query for a list of format rows. The challenges are several:
   + There is a compound foreign key.
   + I need to filter the formats to a subset that contains related Fields.
   + The related fields must match an arbitrary number of filter criteria before being inner-joined to the formats.

So to walk through this:
The Stored Proc receives the following table valued parameter:

```
_FieldDisplayName_  Field_Value
 Field 1             001
 Field 2             002
```

It then needs to filter the Fields table by those values.

Since I needed to use ALL of the criteria and not just one of them, I did not know how work with this to retrieve something useful to join with, when I didn't know how many values I'd have, or what the FieldDisplayName values would be.

@Joe Phillips was smart enough to see through the chaos and suggest that I needed to pivot the table. That's this:

**Edit:**
The following is working to pivot the data, but I am not sure it is ideal. Still waiting on other ideas before supplying an answer.

Instead of using a TVP, I'm using a temp table and dynamic SQL (and yes, I see the injection vulnerability):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[tempdb].[dbo].[#FilterFields]') is not null
Drop Table dbo.#FilterFields

CREATE Table #FilterFields (FieldDisplayName varchar(50), FieldValue nvarchar(max))
/* Just some example data */
INSERT INTO #FilterFields (FieldDisplayName, FieldValue) VALUES ('PTNUM', '011')
INSERT INTO #FilterFields (FieldDisplayName, FieldValue) VALUES('SITENUM', '001')

Declare @column_names varchar(max)
Declare @dynamic_pivot_query as varchar(max)

SELECT @column_names = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + FieldDisplayName + ']'
                FROM #FilterFields FOR xml path('')),1,1,'')

PRINT(@column_names)    

SET @dynamic_pivot_query =
'select * ' +
'from tempdb.dbo.#FilterFields ' +
'Pivot
(
MIN(
    FieldValue
    )
FOR FieldDisplayName IN (' + @column_names + ')
) as P'

PRINT(@dynamic_pivot_query)
EXEC(@dynamic_pivot_query)
```

Comment: I think you're looking to pivot the data?

Comment: Actually, that's an interesting idea -- I hadn't thought of that. Let me dig into that. I don't think I even realized previously that T-SQL had a pivot function.

Comment: Could you post some example data and the expected output? It is not quite clear (at least to me) what you are looking for.

Comment: @SebastianMeine, I will definitely update the post more fully tomorrow; I have to sign off for the night before the wife kills me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*, -- select on the rows you want to display by specifying
        b.*  -- their column name instead of using asterisk *
FROM    Formats a
        INNER JOIN Fields b
            ON  a.BatchID = b.BatchID AND
                a.SequenceID = b.SequenceID
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a compound key (functionally) with a list of values you'll want to leverage IN with a sub-select. To do this, you'll need to combine the fields and that will mean knowing at least a little about the probable data because you'll want to combine them in a way that will be unique for each key pair. If the BatchID and SequenceID are set length strings, then just adding them is probably enough. If they vary, you may need a separator that doesn't appear in either like a dash or ampersand. I'll demonstrate here.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Formats format 
WHERE   format.BatchID + '-' + format.SequenceID  IN 
    (SELECT field.BatchID + '-' + field.SequenceID
     FROM Fields field
           INNER JOIN #FilterFields filter
               ON filter.FieldDisplayName = field.FieldDisplayName AND
                  filter.FieldValue = field.FieldValue)
```

Since you're using an inner join on the table parameter, it'll filter the field table based on pairings of those values and return only the combined key of the Fields table that match.

Comment: This is indeed where I started, but remember that I'm basically filtering the formats table based on a list of criteria (which consist of Key-Value-Pairs of FieldDisplayName and FieldValue). Therefore, the number of joins required is arbitrary.

Comment: That becomes more difficult because of the composite key. I'll see if I can't come up with an alternative.